# .Net Web API PDF Download Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, asp.net-web-api, download, durandal

I'm working on a Durandal application based in a .Net MVC5 project. I have a Web API 2 controller that generates a PDF by taking some data and merging it into existing PDF template using [FDFToolkit](http://fdftoolkit.codeplex.com/). This works just fine, and I can save the new PDF to disk. **My problem is that I want to stream the new PDF to the browser so the user can download it - but it's not working.** I've tried many solutions to no avail.

Ideally, I'd rather not even save the generated PDF to disk as it doesn't seem necessary. That's the first way I attempted this - by keeping it all in memory and writing the new PDF to a byte array and sending that back to the browser. After trying every solution I could find, I settled on saving the new file to disk and trying to stream that new file to the browser. I figured that would help narrow down the problem.

#### Here are my response headers after the api request

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 169729
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myEticket.pdf
```

#### *But nothing happens in the browser (latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, and IE).*

#### Here's my controller and the download method:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/tickets")]
[AllowAnonymous] // for debugging only
public class EticketsController : ApiController
{
     [HttpGet,HttpPost, Route("download")]
    public HttpResponseMessage DownloadPdf([FromBody] Eticket model)
    {
        const string templateName = "eTicketFinal.pdf";
        const string outputname = "eTicket_new.pdf";

        var templatePdfPath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/eTickets/"), templateName);
        var outputpath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/eTickets/"), outputname);

        var eticket = _unitOfWork.EticketRepository.GetById(model.EticketId);

        var pdfticket = Mapper.Map<EticketPdf>(eticket);

        using (var fdfApp = new FDFApp_Class())
        {
            using (var fdfDoc = fdfApp.FDFCreate())
            {
                var properties = pdfticket.GetType().GetProperties();

                foreach (var prop in properties)
                {
                    var name = prop.Name;
                    var propvalue = prop.GetValue(pdfticket, null);
                    var value = propvalue == null ? string.Empty : propvalue.ToString();

                    fdfDoc.FDFSetValue(name, value);
                }

                // this is working and creating the file on disk
                fdfDoc.PDFMergeFDF2File(outputpath, templatePdfPath);                  
                fdfDoc.FDFClose();
            }
        }

        var stream = new FileStream(outputpath, FileMode.Open);

        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StreamContent(stream)
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        //use attachment to force download
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new   ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "myEticket.pdf"
        };
        return result;

    }
}
```

#### The Javascript making the api request:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/tickets/download',
            data: postdata,
            datatype: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        });
```

I'm using Durandal/Knockout/Breeze on the client side, and I'm using EF6, Breeze, and Web API2 server side. I've made sure that the folder containing the PDFs has full security rights, and I put the `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` attribute on the `modules` element in my web.config.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a byte array no problem.  Your server code looks fine to me.

I would guess that the problem is that you can't use XHR/ajax type requests to trigger the file download workflow in the browser.  All you need to do is render a `<a>` link in the HTML with the href pointing to your API endpoint.  You also need to change the server action method to be a GET.

When the user clicks on the link, it will do a GET and the resulting response will trigger the File Download dialog.  If you put the media type `application/pdf` then browsers like Chrome will render it directly.

Comment: an example would have been just tops